# How to get specific folder like WhatsApp (.Status) folder in android 11 using MediaStore Api in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Here is the code to get the specific path in android 11 but unfortunately  I am getting that path like /WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses in android studio

```
    {
Uri=collection
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        } else {
            collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }
        String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
        String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses%"};
        String[] parameters = new String[0];
       Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
           collection,projection,selection,selectionArgs, sortOrder)}
```

Comment: You are supplying that path/folders. And there is no code where you try to retrieve a path. And what does this have to do with Android Studio?

Comment: please guide me how to do that @blackapp

Comment: `I am getting that path like /WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses i` Please show your code.

Comment: Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                collection,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder
        )   while (cursor.moveToNext()) {  }

Comment: and my access also not going in if condition it return me null means there is no path

Comment: Post complete code in your post. Not pieces in comments.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: no bro I didn't find answer tile now

Comment: any solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android 11 and 12 when you get a specific folder then you can only use Storage Access Framework permission that is runtime permission

Answer (score 0):

```java
val STATUS_DIRECTORY = File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses")
```

use  this in to fetch what's app status